# How is the Riemann zeta function zero at the negative even integers?

Tags: riemann-zeta, divergent-series

I'm not sure if I'm misunderstanding this in any way, but surely evaluating the zeta function at, say, -2, would give

$1 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2 + 5^2 + ...$

which seems to diverge to infinity. What am I missing?